# MVC4 Custom 404 page?

Tags: web-config, asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-404

I've place this in web.config `<system.webServer>`

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" path="/cv/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

The path that is used temporarily here [myapplication]/cv/ returns a page.

But if I go to [myapplication]/[anything that doesn't exists] to get a 404 response, juste nothing happens.

This is currently working on my old web form site, but I can't get it working on a MVC4 site.
How can I make this work ? (I don't want to use the "Redirect/File" methods)

Answer (score 10):

This is what I have in a current MVC 4 project:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/General">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Http404" />
</customErrors>
```

I have an Errors controller, and views for "General" and "Http404" (action methods).

Works like a charm.

Comment: I've tried this numerous times, but it keeps displaying the default asp error page

Comment: Did you also create an error controller and the views?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905164/how-to-make-custom-error-pages-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: I did. However, I found my problem. I was actually returning an HttpStatusCodeResult like the framework would, normally. Apparently, that isn't picked up as an error so the custom error pages never get called. I changed my code to throw an HttpException instead and it works now. Not sure how I feel about it

Answer (score 3):

Part of the problem might also stem from the fact that the `<customErrors>` tag is not a valid child of `<system.webServer>`. Try putting it in `<system.web>` instead.